Cron issues when running python script in TMUX for a different conda environment
I have been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a while now and would like to ask for your help.
Let's say that I need to run model.py inside a tmux session. Here are my steps for this to work:

Create tmux session
Activate conda environment model_env
Run model.py

This will run using the packages that I need (mostly for data science work, ex: numpy and pandas) and will eventually run the script without any errors.
However, I've been trying to schedule this run using cron and encountered the following:

I print debugged the script and saw that the packages used are still using my "base" env and not my conda model_env.
This will in turn, generate errors since the numpy package is incorrect.

This is how my .sh file looks like:
#!/bin/bash

# Activate conda environment
conda activate model_env

# Name of the tmux session
SESSION_NAME="tmux_session"

# Path to your Python interpreter
PYTHON_PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python3"

# Path to your Python script
SCRIPT_PATH="/home/ubuntu/model/model.py"

# Log file
LOG_FILE="/home/ubuntu/cron_scheduler/logs/model/model_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').log"

# Start a new tmux session if it doesn't exist
tmux has-session -t $SESSION_NAME 2>/dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION_NAME
fi

# Run the script in the tmux session
tmux send-keys -t $SESSION_NAME "$PYTHON_PATH $SCRIPT_PATH >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1" C-m

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

When you join a tmux session the environment inside that session will be what it was when the session was created; it is not what you set in your calling script.
So what might work is to have a second wrapper script that calls the conda setup and then calls your python script, and have that wrapper script be the one that you call with tmux send-keys.  This will ensure your environment is setup correctly for your execution no matter how the tmux session itself was initially created.
eg (this is untested!!) your cron job could be
#!/bin/bash

# Name of the tmux session
SESSION_NAME="tmux_session"

# Start a new tmux session if it doesn't exist
tmux has-session -t $SESSION_NAME 2>/dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION_NAME
fi

# Run the script in the tmux session
tmux send-keys -t $SESSION_NAME "/home/ubuntu/run-model.sh" C-m

And the wrapper script (run-model.sh in this example) could be
#!/bin/bash

# Activate conda environment
conda activate model_env

# Path to your Python interpreter
PYTHON_PATH="/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python3"

# Path to your Python script
SCRIPT_PATH="/home/ubuntu/model/model.py"

# Log file
LOG_FILE="/home/ubuntu/cron_scheduler/logs/model/model_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').log"

$PYTHON_PATH $SCRIPT_PATH >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1

Basically, separate out the "run stuff in tmux" part and the "configure my environment and run my app" part.
You may also want to set other environment variables (eg PATH) before calling conda if you need other non-standard values.
